# Any method to make specific widget for every post and page?

Tags: plugins, php

is here any method , that can make specific widget for each post and page? I mean, for example here is widget html:

```
<div id="heatmapthemead-secondary-sidebar-container" role="complementary">
<h4 class="widget-title">bla bla bla </p></div></div>
```

But can i make different text here for every page and posts? Any help of `function.php` ?
For example for Post 1 it should show   NEw york
for post 2  washington and so on. Different widget for all posts?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do what you want with the [Category Country Aware (CCA) Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/category-country-aware/). (it's for use within post/page content but also includes the widget below).

**Option 1:** (only for posts and if you are happy to create one off categories):

- Create new categories for say "Washington" and "NY" via WP Admin
  `Dashboard -> posts -> categories`.
- In the post editor associate each post with the relevant new
  category.
- Add an entry (text, HTML, JavaScript) with specific content for "NY"
  to the CCA widget, save then repeat for "Washington" etc (example below).

[image: Category Country Widget]

.
You can use multiple CCA widgets ("text" or "RSS"), so you could use a second widget to say display local news for that city.

**Option 2:** If you want it to work with pages, or don't want give posts an extra unique category, want to use shortcodes, or would like to use the widget as a canvas for your own PHP then:

- Additionally install this (free) [Extension to the Category Country Plugin](http://wptest.means.us.com/cca-goodies-extension/)

You can then add a custom field cca_category and value (e.g "Washington") to your posts and pages.  The CCA widget will check if the post has a matching "cca_category" before checking for a matching WordPress category. (Section 4 of above link provides details on how to do this).

Declaration of interest! : I'm the plugin author.